# Material-UI CSV/PDF Print Export does not work using "@mui/x-data-grid" module

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, export

This could be a silly question but I'm confuse and this doesn't make sense unless I'm missing something. I wanted to print my data as a PDF using the export option since is available for everyone according to the documentation, however I do not get to see the option, I can only see the CSV option ?

[image]

while on their example they have access to both CSV and Print
[MUI - Export](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/)

[image]

I also checked their code to see if they "added" something extra but is seems to be completely normal, they are even using the normal one and not the pro

[image]

And even if if they were using PRO is available for both options pro and free.

[image]

Am I missing something, is it no longer available ?
This is what I have, I'm not missing anything...

**UPDATE** I just removed everything I wasn't using and is still not working

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {DataGrid, GridToolbar} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

function VerPedidos() {

    const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("verpedidos"))

    let librosData = data[0].data
    
    const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);
    const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = useState([]);
    const columns = [
        { field: 'descripcion', headerName: 'Descripción', width: 450 },

        {field: 'tipo', headerName: 'Tipo', width: 150},
      
        {field: 'editorial', headerName: 'Editorial', width: 100},
      
        {field: 'precio', headerName: 'Precio', width: 100, align: 'right', sortable: false,
        valueFormatter: (params) => {
        return `$${params.value}`;
      }}
      ]

    return (
        <DataGrid 
        rows={librosData}
        columns={columns}
        autoHeight 

        pageSize={pageSize}
        onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}

        components={{
          Toolbar: GridToolbar,
        }}
      />
    )
}

export default VerPedidos
```

[image]

**package.json**

```
 "name": "venta_de_libros",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-generator": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "devextreme": "21.1.5",
    "devextreme-react": "21.1.5",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Just added both of them

Comment: maaaan I'm gonna go mad if things stop working out of nowhere, fixed an issue I had with refresh for 2 weeks to find out all I had to do after 3 questions, 2 forums was to add user as a dependency array.  why nothing never works! is never simple jesus christ.

Comment: I think it could be because I do not use ExportSelectorGrid but I though that was just for importing data from the random data generator, maybe is that ?

Comment: Updating code to what I attempt (Still not working btw) deleted everything I don't need and just left what I want to check

Comment: Could it be that I'm outdated ?

Comment: oh my then I'm just unlucky I'm gonna leave it here thanks for the help though I give up, gonna work on something else meanwhile

Comment: Thank you I'll take that in consideration but I still have to finish the edit row code, the export and I need to learn about conditional rendering because I want to add an adm view (I have all the adm view coded) I just need to understand conditional rendering. Oh and I have to lock refresh some stuff and force user to use buttons to get out of certain window. lots of things to do, more research time

Comment: yeah I saw the print option there but idk why I don't see the print option in my work which is why I wanna fix it

Comment: I'll make a new project and try to see if I have the print option or not that way I can discard a few things.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I did a complete new project and the print option was available so I do not have any idea of how to fix this in this project because I have not remove any option of printing.

Comment: I'm gonna try and update my packages maybe that will fix it. Is there a place where I can see the latest versions? I feel MUI web page is quite outdated but I could be wrong

Comment: The thing is if I just add for example the table, it doesn't let me export with PRINT. I can't narrow more than that

Comment: @NearHuscarl Just updated code on the question can't seem to find an error :c

Comment: All I can think of is to make a github so people can help or something cause I have no clue

Comment: What :c it doesn't work on mine god

Comment: does it have to be a minimal project ? I'm about to clone the whole thing

Comment: Like I can't make anything more minimal than that piece of code I just updated I do not know what the issue is.

Comment: I just added all the packages

Comment: Man out of nowhere now the option is available. I haven't done A N Y T H I N G

Comment: Also I can't see that option I get to see the exports but not the options in the inspect *updating picture*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

You need to update your `package.json` dependencies. You need to have this dependencies in your package

```
{

  // Other package.json code ...

  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.0.4",
    "@mui/material": "5.0.4",
    "@mui/styles": "5.0.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "5.0.0-beta.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  },

  // Other package.json code ...
}
```

Please pay attention to the version of the dependencies specially the `@mui/x-data-grid` it should be version `"5.0.0-beta.5`.

I also recommend to remove this dependencies from your `package.json`'

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
```

Your print export should still work even if without that dependencies above. Also I see that you are using `"@mui/material" so I think you would not need those dependencies.

You may also play the demonstration I created in the CodeSandbox the link is **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wright-xejdy?file=/package.json)**

As of this writing the only working version that I've known about `"@mui/x-data-grid"` that you can use to implement CSV/Print Export is version `"5.0.0-beta.5"` and `"5.0.0-beta.4"`.

---

###### How to install the right version of `"@mui/x-data-grid"` that supports CSV/PDF export ?

```
  yarn add @mui/x-data-grid@5.0.0-beta.5 or npm i @mui/x-data-grid@5.0.0-beta.5
```

###### What do I need to do if I have issues after installing those needed dependencies ?

```
Most package or dependencies related Issues if it's not due to network can be resolve by deleting node_modules folder and lock files (package-lock.json or yarn.lock) and installing all dependencies again by running npm install or yarn
```

**For reference you may also browse this [Github Repo](https://github.com/duterte/dataGrid)**

Comment: Yeah we figure out that in the end after many tries of different things

Comment: @ReactPotato Good to know

Comment: I forgot to ask why remove the core ? cause core is used for other things also data grid is no longer data grid I understand that one now is x-data-grid but why the core

Comment: Its no longer needed when you use this version of data-grid `5.0.0-beta.5` and `5.0.0-beta.4`